# Contentful API with React how to get specific fields from array items instead of whole arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contentful, contentful-api

I'm was trying to look for ways to make my website load faster and after running speed tests I understood that I was making a mistake in the way I'm loading data from contentful. I have a page with all the blogs listed in it (with just their `title` and `image` and a handful other details visible in the list of blogs) and instead of loading only the necessary fields from contentful I'm loading all the fields for each array item(`post`) of the array `posts` which naturally takes up a lot of time and makes my page slow. How can I load only specific fields from contentful for the blog list page but load all the fields when we click on an individual blog from the list. I'm using react static and this is how my config file looks for the posts section where the path `/blog` is the main blog list page and `/container/Post` is the individual blog page.

```
let posts = await client
      .getEntries({
        content_type: "blogPost",
        order: "-sys.createdAt",
        include: 1,
      })
      .then((response) => response.items)
      .catch(console.error);
    console.log("Post -> ", posts.length);

    posts = posts.sort((a, b) => {
      let keyA = new Date(a.fields.date);
      let keyB = new Date(b.fields.date);
      // Compare the 2 dates
      if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
      if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
```

And in my return statement

```
{
        path: "/blog",
        getData: () => ({
          posts,
        }),
        children: posts.map((post) => ({
          path: `/${urlBuilder(
            post.fields.url ? post.fields.url : post.fields.title
          )}`,
          template: "src/containers/Post",
          getData: () => ({
            post,
          }),
        })),
      },
```

This is how my `posts` returned from contentful looks like

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using GraphQL? You could easily grab only the data your interested this way.  https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/schema-generation/entries

Comment: I'm a beginner in React and I've never used GraphQL, I've been using content delivery API from the contentful sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `select` operator. What this translates into when using the contentful sdk is something like this:

```js
const contentful = require('contentful')

const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: '<space_id>',
  environment: '<environment_id>',
  accessToken: '<content_delivery_api_key>'
})

client.getEntries({
  content_type: '<content_type_id>',
  select: 'sys.id,fields.<field_name>'
})
.then((response) => console.log(response.items))
.catch(console.error)
```

Pay special attention to the `select: 'sys.id,fields.<field_name>'` section. This is where you can specify only what fields you want returned.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but will doing this prevent me from getting all the remaining fields necessary for the individual blog pages? I still need all the fields for every item in the `posts` array for those individual blog pages

Comment: The request above should not be used/confused for a request to get all information you could ever need for a given blog page. When you route a user to a blog page you'll make another request for all of the data you need for that page.

Comment: Oh but wouldn't that make no difference in terms of increasing speed if we're still getting all the information in a different request

Comment: The difference is you're only getting "all the information" for ONE blog post, not every blog post. In other words the first request is for only the title, description, url, etc of every post (all you need to display the available posts). You then click on a post and are routed to that specific post. Obviously you need more information than just the title, description, and url once you get there, so you make a secondary request just for that posts information.

Comment: @dharman `select: 'sys.id,fields.<field_name>'` doesn't seem like the right syntax

Comment: `fields.<field_name>` is just a generic example they provide. Their documentation may be helpful to provide more clarity:  https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/select-operator

Comment: yeah I checked out their documentation and couldn't find an efficient way to add more than 1 field as `fields.<field_name>` works only for a single field

Comment: You'll need to separate with commas. e.g. `sys.id,fields.productName,fields.description,fields.updatedAt,fields.tags`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234430/discussion-between-cassandra-and-coloradocolby).